# p-value inside r for Tableau

Tags: r, p-value

First - I am not a statistician. Please be kind. :)

I have received a requirement from my stakeholders to show a p-value between two values. We use Tableau to show our analysis and are told that we need to use the R connection to get the p-values at the level we need. So, today, I'm looking for a calculation in r that would provide a p-value for the given use case...

- x # of users make a given choice
- y # of users make the same choice later in the website
- z is the # of users in the website.
- what is the p-value of the change from x to y?

I believe at current we use a paired proportion test to determine a p-value in a different system.

Any light you can shed would be most welcome.

Comment: are the users the same in x and y?

Comment: Take a look at [McNemar's chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test) and its [implementation in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/mcnemar.test.html).

Comment: so `y` would be a proportion of `x` and `x` a proportion of `z`?  And you're interested in the difference in these proportions?